# Problema con Web Scraping al crear un Data Frame en R

Tags: r, rstudio, rvest

Estoy realizando Web Scraping para obtener dos variables `precio` y `area`. Sucede que `precio` tiene un `length()` mayor que `area` dado que no todas las publicaciones tienen area. Con la información debo crear un data frame pero como el largo de los datos es distintos es imposible, sí se pudiera lograr ensamblar dos variables con distintos largos sería imposible unir cada `precio` con cada `area`. La pregunta es Cómo se puede scrapear los datos de manera que cuando no existe `area` en ese elemento de la lista haya un string de algún tipo por ejemplo NA?.
Estoy utilizando el paquete `rvest`

En este link tienen el mismo problema pero no está resuelto.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996952/r-rvest-getting-2-elements-nodes-at-the-same-time

El código es

```
library(rvest)
library(robotstxt)
library(selectr)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(forcats)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

url = "https://capital-federal.properati.com.ar/nf/propiedades/venta/"
paths_allowed(paths = c(url))

# Leer el HTML
leahtml <- read_html(url)

leahtml %>%
  html_nodes(".price") %>%
  html_text() -> price

leahtml %>%
  html_nodes(".area") %>%
  html_text() -> area

leahtml %>%
  html_nodes(".location") %>%
  html_text() -> location

precio = gsub("\n","",price)
precio = gsub("exp","",precio)
precio_a = gsub("\\$","",precio)
precio_b = gsub("US","",precio_a)
precio_limpio = gsub("\\.","",precio_b)
precio_limpio = str_trim(precio_limpio)
precio_su= substr(precio_limpio,1,5)
precio_su= as.numeric(precio_su)

area_a = gsub("\n","",area)
area_b = gsub("m²","",area_a)
area_limpia = as.numeric(area_b)

dataset <- data.frame(location, area_limpia, precio_su)
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega la url que estás intentando "escrapear" y el código que tengas hasta ahora. Saludos

Comment: Ya modifiqué la pregunta @PatricioMoracho. Disculpas por la desprolijidad del código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema, ya te habrás dados cuenta, es que hay propiedades que no tienen `area`, por lo que no te sirve capturar `precio` y `area` por separado. Debes trabajar sobre el nodo que representa cada propiedad y sobre estos elementos buscar cada dato. Una forma rápida, sería:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url = "https://capital-federal.properati.com.ar/nf/propiedades/venta/"

read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('.item-description')  %>% 
  map_df( ~ {
              precio = html_nodes(.x, ".price") %>%  html_text() %>% str_replace_all( pattern="\n| ", repl="")
              area = html_nodes(.x, ".area") %>%  html_text() %>% str_replace_all( pattern="[\n| ] ", repl="")
              area <- ifelse(length(area)>0, area, NA_character_)
              list(precio=precio, area=area)
  }) 


# A tibble: 18 x 2
   precio                area    
   <chr>                 <chr>   
 1 U$S930.000$16082exp   " 285m²"
 2 U$S990.000            " 116m²"
 3 U$S160.000            " 120m²"
 4 U$S120.000            " 55m²" 
 5 U$S2.200.000           NA     
 6 U$S178.359            " 65m²" 
 7 U$S258.000$11500exp   " 157m²"
 8 U$S749.000$25500exp   " 111m²"
 9 U$S230.000$2157138exp " 134m²"
10 U$S112.000$4500exp    " 61m²" 
11 U$S280.000             NA     
12 U$S170.000$4000exp    " 72m²" 
13 U$S480.000             NA     
14 U$S250.000             NA     
15 U$S125.000$3500exp    " 66m²" 
16 U$S340.000             NA     
17 U$S258.000$15000exp   " 86m²" 
18 U$S120.000            " 55m²"
```

Detalle:

- Iteramos por los nodos `.item-description` que engloba a cada propiedad
- Usando `map_df` por cada elemento extraemos ahora sí, el area y el precio, agregué un reemplazo de algunos caracteres con `str_replace_all()` simplemente para que la salida se vea más clara.
- Finalmente `map_df` nos retorna un `tibble` con cada propiedad y sus variables.

Comment: Gracias. Ahora realice una función para que extraiga 50 hojas y me queda una lista conformada por tres atributos. Me trae 50 listas como la de tu resultado, pero cómo puedo transformarlo en df ya que tienen distinto números de columnas.

Comment: ¿Por que distinto número de columnas? si replicaste el código de mi respuesta cada lista debería tener el mismo número de columnas. Si ese fuera el caso podrías probar con `bind_rows()` .

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda @Patricio Moracho. Ya lo solucioné usando ```do.call(rbind, web_data) ``` donde  ```web_data  = lapply(url, pags) function(todo el código que propusiste) ```